# Trouble accessing a variable to use in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to dynamically set a resource file for a python class I'm building. My idea of tackling this was to initially set the variable to `None` and then assign it using a module level function. What my module looks like:

```
# my_module

df = None

def set_data(fp, sheet_name, index_col=[0, 1]):
    # what I really want to do:
    df = pd.read_excel(rf'{fp}', index_col=index_col)

    # minimal example:
    df = 'Foo'

class DataSet():
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = df
```

Here is the result I get when testing this out. What am I missing here?

```
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.df == None
True
>>> my_module.set_data('file.xlsx', 'sheet_1')
>>> my_module.df == None
True
>>> my_module.df == 'Foo'
False
```

Comment: You are creating a local `df` in `set_data`, you can declare `global df` before `df = ...` to change the outer `df`. But simpler would just be take the arguments to `set_data()` in `DataSet.__init__()`.

Comment: @Achampion I also initially thought of using global but read that it isn't performant. Thanks for your solution by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more canonical form would be:

```
def set_data(fp, sheet_name, index_col=[0, 1]):
    # what I really want to do:
    return pd.read_excel(rf'{fp}', index_col=index_col)

class DataSet():
    def __init__(self, fp, sheet_name, index_col=[0, 1]):
        self.df = set_data(fp, sheet_name, index_col)
```

Then you would just create your `DataSet()`, e.g.:

```
>>> dataset = my_module.DataSet('file.xlsx', 'sheet_1')
>>> dataset.df
```

As a class variable:

```
class DataSet():
    df = None

    @classmethod
    def set_data(cls, fp, sheet_name, index_col=[0, 1]):
        cls.df = pd.read_excel(rf'{fp}', index_col=index_col)
```

Use:

```
>>> my_module.DataSet.set_data('file.xlsx', 'sheet_1')
>>> dataset = my_module.DataSet()
>>> dataset.df
```

You can also directly access `df` from the `class` without creating an instance:

```
>>> my_module.DataSet.df
```

Comment: what if I only want to create one shared version of df that is used by DataSet() instances?